# devDependencies in node js application in flex app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

in the Standard environment in GAE it stays that devDevependencies from package.json are [ignored](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies). But there are no such limitations for the [Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-nodejs-libraries). However, I'm getting parcel not found error while trying to deploy my app to GAE.
Here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -w ./server bin/runServer -e js,json",
    "build:client": "parcel build client/index.html",
    "start": "npm run build:client && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/runServer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.1.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-multi-lang": "^1.0.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
    "parcel": "^1.10.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.10.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last I checked, App Engine doesn't install devDependencies because it used `npm install --production` by default.  If you want to make sure those get installed, you have a few options:

1. You could move everything into the `dependencies` section
2. You could define your own `Dockerfile`, and run regular `npm install` inside of it before starting
3. (probably the best) You could use a [Multi-stage docker build](https://codefresh.io/docker-tutorial/node_docker_multistage/) to perform your build step in the first stage, and generate a different slimmer image that only has what you need.

Hope this helps!